Spivak: Prove $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p$ can be written in the form $\frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}+An^p+Bn^{p-1}+Cn^{p-2}........$
I tried to prove this using complete induction... with $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{2}$ as the base case. Now, assuming said property holds for $\sum_{}^{}k,\sum_{}^{}k^2,...,\sum_{}^{}k^p$ we must show $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{p+1}$$ can be written in the form $$\frac{n^{p+2}}{p+2}+An^{p+1}+Bn^p+....$$
Utilizing the telescoping property of sums
$$(n+1)^{p+2}-1=\binom{p+2}{1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{p+1}+\binom{p+2}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p+...$$
For simplicity sake we will denote $$S=\binom{p+2}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p+\binom{p+2}{3}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{p-1}+...\binom{p+2}{p+2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k$$
Algebraically this leaves us with $$\frac{(n+1)^{p+2}}{p+2}-\frac{(S+1)}{p+2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{p+1}$$
Once final algebraic push and were left with
$$\frac{(n+1)^{p+2}}{p+2}-\frac{S+1}{p+2}=\frac{n^{p+2}}{p+2}+\frac{\binom{p+2}{1}n^{p+1}}{p+2}+...+\frac{\binom{p+2}{p+1}n}{p+2}-\frac{S}{p+2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{p+1}$$
Q.E.D
I apologize if this proof is very messy, I am nothing but a novice. I would appreciate if someone could verify it, as this proof  appears correct to me, yet not very rigorous. My main gripe is with the term $S$, as it is quite messy. However, since it's of degree
$p+1$ I don't think it matters much. The important part is that the structure $$\frac{n^{p+2}}{p+2}+An^{p+1}+...$$ for whatever $A$ represents holds

I would do it with induction on $p$.
Suppose we proved it up to $p$ and note
$$
\frac{i^{p+2}-(i-1)^{p+2}}{p+2}=i^{p+1}+\sum_{k=0} c_{k,p} i^{p-k}
$$
Summing over $i=1,...,n$ gives
$$
\frac{n^{p+2}}{p+2}=\sum_{i=1}^n i^{p+1}+\sum_{k=0} c_{k,p} \sum_{i=1}^n i^{p-k}
$$
that is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i^{p+1}=
\frac{n^{p+2}}{p+2}-\sum_{k=0} c_{k,p} \sum_{i=1}^n i^{p-k}
$$
and now you use the fact that for the sums with pets up to $p$ you have the polynomial representation.

Thank you for your proof. It seems much more simple than what I did. If possible could you take the time to verify whether my proof is correct. I need all the feedback I can get. Thank you!
